# Can I use custom tag names, without using web components, just for styling?

Tags: html, css, web-component

To my suprise, modern browser seem to not complain if I use custom tag names, and then style those tags as if it where normal html tags, they behave like span elements, and like div elements, if I set `display: block;`.

I mean, even if I don't use polymer, or try to register the custom element.

For example, I have this:
https://jsfiddle.net/hvybz0nq/4/

```
<flex-fixed>
  <sections>
    <section>Section 1</section>
    <section>Section 2</section>
    <section>Section 3</section>
    <div>Add Section</div>
  </sections>
  <splitter></splitter>
  <pages>
    <page>Page 1</page>
    <page>Page 2</page>
    <page>Page 3</page>
    <div>Add Page </div>
  </pages>
</flex-fixed>
```

With some css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

flex-fixed, sections, section, div, pages, page {
  display: flex;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

flex-fixed {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column; 
  position: fixed;
}

section {
  border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

splitter {
  height: 1px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

pages {
  height: 100%;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgrey;
  align-self:flex-end; 
  flex-direction: column;
}

page {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

section, page, div {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. Your document may look fine now, but what if a future browsers uses those tag names for real elements. Take the `<picture>` element for instance; if you would have used that for your experiments a couple of years ago, that would not have been a problem.

Comment: So if you must use custom elements, use names starting with `x-`.

Comment: Or, as an alternative approach, use xml rather than html.

Comment: Another reason to avoid this besides accessibility is maintainability. Every new person that goes onto a project has to learn every single new tag, what it's meant to do, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Please note: prompted by a user comment to return to this a couple years later, I want to point out that this is outdated; if the question were posted today I'd give a very different answer.  People are generally a lot less freaked out by the idea of custom elements here in the brave new year of 2018.  Original 2016 answer follows:*

You absolutely can do this.  It will work.  Custom elements are part of the [HTML5 spec](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/);  explicit support for unregistered custom elements is included (see section 7). They're supported in all modern browsers (by default they are treated as inline elements, just like `<span>`), there's first-class support for them in Angular.js for example.   Functionally speaking there is no difference at all between `<foo>` and `<span class="foo">`.

So should you? I break it down like this:

**Reasons not to use custom elements**

- Some older browsers (IE8 and prior) will only support them if you use a javascript shim (at least `document.createElement('foo')`.)
- HTML validators (or some HTML editors that attempt to validate your code) may choke on those tags or interpret them as errors. This ranges from non-issue to total deal-breaker, depending on your workflow.
- Future compatibility. Depending on the tag names you choose, there is a nonzero chance that any custom tag name you invent will, at some point in the future, become blessed as a "real" html tag which carries specific behavior that you weren't expecting.  **Update in 2018**: the current convention is to include a hyphen in the name of all custom elements, which removes this risk; future HTML, SVG and MathML elements will never contain hyphens in their name.
- You'll have to spend a lot of time explaining to aghast developers and maintainers that no, it's fine, it really does work, no it's not XML, yes it will work with screenreaders, yes it does look weird but it's totally ok honest look there is right in the spec
- There's generally no particular reason to do so, because `<span class="foo">` does the same thing as `<foo>` without the tsuris

**Reasons to use custom elements**

- Because you can

On balance, I don't feel it's worth it.

Comment: "there is a nonzero chance that any custom tag name you invent will ... become blessed as a "real" html tag" <-- This is incorrect. Custom element names contain hyphens; native elements do not; ever. The custom element standard, which all of the major vendors have adopted, guarantees this.  "no elements will be added to HTML, SVG, or MathML with hyphen-containing local names in the future" https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/#custom-elements-core-concepts

Comment: @JeffLaughlin True, and I'll update the answer to include that information -- but note that this answer predates that spec by about ten months....

Comment: Actually, none of the "not" reasons really hold up.

Aghast developers will have to learn all this anyway, just via class names instead of element names. 

The killer pro reason : readability. Custom elements clearly communicate intent/function. <foo> says exactly what it is. <span class="foo">  requires that I jump to the class name to figure it out.

Comment: @ShukriAdams Note that the answer you're commenting on is from 2016; a lot has changed in the last five years. If I were writing this today I wouldn't be worried about IE8 or about people confusing custom elements with XML, but I still would consider issues with validators and the "there's no particular reason to do this in the first place" as valid reasons not to do this.  (I don't agree that `<foo>` is more easily understood than `<span class="foo">`, that's a stretch.)

Comment: `<foo>` is certainly more readable than `<span class="class1 class2 foo class3">`, don't you agree?

Comment: @meizy no, not necessarily, assuming those various classnames have meaningful reuse across the app. The question being answered here was "can I use custom elements *just for styling*" -- blessing one of the classes as the tag name implies there's a lot more importance to "foo" than to "class1, class2, class3". Or if you meant lumping all the styling rules from all the classnames into just "foo" (whether as a tag name or a classname), that would only make sense if there wasn't a good reason to have those classes separate in the first place -- which may or may not be the case.