# Is it safe to create Custom HTML Tags?

Tags: javascript, html

I am reading about a technique wherein you can create custom HTML tags, like so:

```
<!-- REGISTER CUSTOM ELEMENTS -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ApplicationContainer = document.registerElement('application-container');
    document.body.appendChild(new ApplicationContainer());
</script>
```

Given there is a variety of browsers & browser-versions out there, I was wondering:

- Is it safe to create custom tags yet?
- If not, what is the proper work-around?

...I'm just curious, really.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to solve an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: The only application of custom HTML tags I'm familiar with is through a framework like Angular that allows you to "register" custom directives to encapsulate DOM manipulations, so effectively, you're "creating" new elements, but they're simply extended functionality based on the core set of HTML elements, not a "brand new" element per se.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve anything.  I just read the article & thought..."that cant be safe."   I even said so in the 1st line of the question...and ended with a "just curious"

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use custom tag names, without using web components, just for styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35001173/can-i-use-custom-tag-names-without-using-web-components-just-for-styling)

Comment: TL;DR is it's totally safe and legal, and most people will still tell you not to do it anyway.  And they're probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@PrisonerZER0 I wouldn't call "Olde browsers" the word "safe". Somewhat of an oxymoron. Even M$ has put IE in a coffin. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support

Us supporting them is only asking for trouble. Thanks for the shout.

I created the [`snuggsi ツ` *(https://github.com/devpunks/snuggsi)*](https://github.com/devpunks/snuggsi) library as a suite of conventions over the web components/custom elements native browser spec. My philosophy is you shouldn't need to know node, webpack, babel, etc. Should only need to know basic HTML,CSS,JS to be productive in 2017. The following snippet is a perfect example.

Feel free to reach out on github as it seems like you are up to snuff with modern platform development. We won't need these convoluted front end tools where we are going Feel free to reach out on github so i can help you get started!

```html
<hello-world>
 Hello {planet}
</hello-world>

<!-- more info @ https://github.com/devpunks/snuggsi -->
<script src=//unpkg.com/snuggsi></script>
<script>

// Element Definition -----------------------------

Element `hello-world`

// Class Description ------------------------------

(class extends HTMLElement {

  get planet ()
    // "automagic" token binding
    { return 'world ' }

  onclick ()
    // "automagic" event registration
    { alert (this) }
})

</script>
```

Comment: Nice...I will definitely take a look at it

Comment: How do you re-use these components in different pages?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not recommended unless you have some sort of polyfill. It is unsupported in most browsers, see [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements).

There are a few known polyfills however they do have their setbacks. [WebComponents Repository](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend that. you should be able to implement whatever you need using existing HTML tags. you need to think of your requirements again. do you need a new HTML tag to make it distinctive from existing ones? if yes you can always use data attributes to distinguish it from others. but if you essentially need to create a custom tag, [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/customelements) has a very interesting walk through. hope my answer has been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

According to [snuggsi](https://github.com/devpunks/snuggsi)

> Web Components ARE [ready for production](https://twitter.com/WebReflection/status/761316429559922688)
>
> & [Custom Elements v1](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements) has full [support for every modern browser
>   including Internet Explorer 11+ / Edge](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#browser-support)

It is not immediately clear what you mean by "safe", as that is a rather broad and indefinite term.

Comment: By "safe" I mean Olde browsers too

Comment: Actually quite the opposite @PrisonerZERO. This would be 100% UNSAFE in 2017 and moving forward. Even Microsoft has gone on record stating if you are still supporting anything <11 you have pulled the trigger on your foot machine gun. I've documented this thoroughly in this browser support section of the README https://github.com/devpunks/snuggsi#browser-support