# Googles custom html tags

Tags: html

If you look through the HTML source on some of Google's websites, you'll see tags like `<devsite-snackbar></devsite-snackbar>` that are part of the document body, but are not valid HTML.

How is this allowed, and is it ok to use such custom tags?

Comment: If it's not a pure HTML CSS website, then what sort of website is it? What's the name for such websites?

Comment: Take a look at these resources: [https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) [https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html)

Comment: And also this Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45532302/is-it-safe-to-create-custom-html-tags/45532435

Comment: [angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) also provided with custom html tags.

Comment: Browsers are built to ignore tags they do not know about and just display their content. That's why the `noscript` tag works or the `picture` tag, for example. Previous versions of the browsers couldn't have known that those tag would exist some day.

Answer (score 0):

The web component spec allows for custom element definitions (i.e. custom tags like "devsite-snackbar"). Custom elements are valid so long as each element contains two names separated by a dash. However, elements will only have functionality if they are defined in Javascript. Angular, Lit, Svelte, and numerous other frameworks can be used to create web components, but you can also define them in vanilla JS/HTML. You can find a good guide here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements

Here's simple starter adapted from a [Digital Ocean article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/web-components-your-first-custom-element)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fwuhjo?file=index.ts,index.html